# is there any way to send file from Matlab to clouds like Dropbox?

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to send a file from Matlab to Dropbox or other cloud storage?
for example I want to send an image to my Dropbox account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a function for this on FileExchange:
[FileExchange](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59673-upload-a-file-to-dropbox-directly-from-matlab)

> Description
>
> This function allows a user to upload files using MATLAB to DropBox.
>   The function does not require the user to have the DropBox application
>   installed. It uses publicly documented APIs to upload the file to
>   DropBox using the WEBWRITE function in MATLAB.

You need an API key for using it:
[Generate Access Token](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/)

Comment: It has an error: `No public property HeaderFields exists for class weboptions`. I use matlab 2015b

Comment: R2016b is working - looks like `HeaderFields` is new since 2016b [MathWorks](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=weboptions&startrelease=R2014a&endrelease=R2016b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=weboptions)